# Why isn't alignas() taking a parameter pack?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, g++, clang++

According to [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas)

---

## alignas specifier (since C++11)

Specifies the alignment requirement of a type or an object.

### Syntax

**alignas(** expression **)**
**alignas(** type-id **)**
**alignas(** pack ... **)**

1. `alignas(expression)` must be an integral constant expression that evaluates to zero, or to a valid value for an alignment or extended alignment.
2. Equivalent to `alignas(alignof(type))`
3. Equivalent to multiple alignas specifiers applied to the same declaration, one for each member of the parameter pack, which can be either type or non-type parameter pack.

---

So why don't the following work for g++, clang or VC++?

```
struct alignas(1, 4) A {};
```

or

```
struct alignas(int, double) A {};
```

Is this a defect?

## Edit

Apparently this works for g++ 8.2 and not for clang++ 8.0 or VC++ 19.20.27508.1 so seems to be a defect, and the compilers haven't caught up.

## Edit

Apparently, running MinGW's g++ compiler in a cygwin bash shell causes weird behaviour. Works fine when running in a MinGW's bash shell.  So, no, this doesn't work under g++ 8.2 either.

Comment: GCC 8.2 [seems to reject](https://godbolt.org/z/MOCvtA) the code.

Comment: @Fureeish, not for me.  Works fine at my home computer.

Comment: Can you share your compilation flags? And the exact code? Can you paste it on godbolt, select the same compiler options and specify whether the outcome is the same?

Comment: Very strange.  The only parameter (other than the file name) I'm using is `-std=c++17`, and the file only contains `struct alignas(1,4) A {}; struct alignas(int, double) B {};`

Comment: On godbold, it gives the same error as the others.  On my home computer, there's no message.  Of course, it's not generating an executable either.  Must be something wrong with the install?

Comment: @Fureeish, yeah, it was my install.  See my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1, 4` or `int, double` are not parameter packs. This would be an example of a parameter pack used in this context:

```
template <class... T>
struct Widget
{
  struct alignas(T...) A {};
};
```

Note that it's possible to apply multiple `alignas` specifiers to the same declaration, so your examples can be written as `alignas(1) alignas(4)` and `alignas(int) alignas(double)` respectively.

Comment: Hm, it's confusing why they would introduce the specific `alignas(pack...)` syntax without adding variadic support for `alignas(type-id, ...)` or `alignas(expression, ...)` - it's the only such syntactic choice I can think of. On the one hand we already have `sizeof...(pack)` (even though this is very different from `sizeof(pack)...`) so `alignas...(pack)` would've made the distinction clear. And I don't think `alignas(T)...` would've been particularly confusing either if we're already adding such syntactic special casing. I guess it's some "this is easier for the parser" reason?

Comment: Oh, well, my original idea was to do this `template <typename Base, typename...Deriveds> struct alignas(T, Us...) {};` which I thought would be correct, but given that that would also not be a parameter pack, then yeah.  That's annoying.

Comment: @Adrian But that one is doable as `template </*as before*/> struct alignas(T) alignas(U...) {};`

Comment: Oh.  Didn't realize that multiple could be put on the same line.  Thx.

Comment: @Adrian The very text you quoted for point 3 starts "Equivalent to multiple alignas specifiers applied to the same declaration"

Comment: Still didn't realize that syntactly it was valid.  Thought that it was required to put them in one list if you wanted multiple to be applied.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I also find this syntax inconsistent. However, consider the alternatives. In basically all contexts in which it can be used, a pack expansion expands to a comma-separated list, so `alignas(T)...` wouldn't make too much sense since specifiers are not comma-separated in a normal declaration. `sizeof...` is conceptually very different from `sizeof` in that it returns the size of the parameter pack itself and not the size of what the pack expands to, so `alignas...(T)` also wouldn't make sense as that would logically have to return the alignment of the parameter pack…

Comment: So that basically leaves `alignas(T...)` as the only alternative that is at least not contradictory to pre-existing syntax. I think what ideally would be done is to just specify that `alignas()` can take a comma-separated list of type-ids or constant expressions. That would then make it all consistent again (unless I just haven't thought about it enough and am overlooking some weird corner cases in which it would all break down, which is very much possible)…not sure why it was not originally done like this; probably just because there were more important things to take care of…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel, wouldn't it have been better to go with `alignas(Ts)` where `Ts` is a parameter pack?  But then a reader would have to look at what `Ts` is i guess?

Comment: @Adrian that would imho be very inconsistent with the rest of C++. The basic idea behind variadic templates is that you can expand parameter packs into comma-separated lists in places where doing so would form a valid syntax construct if you just had written such a list there yourself. Using the name of a parameter pack without expanding it would mean that you're doing something with the parameter pack itself rather than its contents. Thus, `alignas(Ts)` would have to be read as "align based on the alignment of `Ts`". A parameter pack doesn't have alignment, so this wouldn't make sense…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel, yes that makes sense.  But that would mean that `alignas(A B C)` and `alignas(1 2 3)` should also work, because, as you said, you're not working with parameter packs.  However, `sizeof...(Ts)` gives the size of the parameter pack, so why not define `alignas(Ts)` as the strongest alignment of the pack? If not that, then I think `alignas...(Ts)` would be better to represent what I just said, but whatever.  It's done now.

Comment: `sizeof...` is a separate kind of sizeof expression that applies to a parameter pack itself (that's why the `...` appear before the parameter pack rather than after, as they would in a pack expansion). Alignment is not a property that parameter packs have. Thus `alignas...(Ts)` would be semantically inconsistent with what `sizeof...(Ts)` does. As said above, I think it would make sense to simply define that `alignas(A, B, C)` and `alignas(1, 2, 4)` specify the strongest alignment from the options given in the list. Then `alignas(Ts...)` would be consistent with "normal" syntax…